# How to Validate Array of Urls using Class-Validator?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, dto, class-validator

I am using Class-Validator to validate Properties of DTOs for Nest.js Application. In there I have a Property "images", which is an Array of Strings and those Strings are Urls. So, I want to validate each and every Url in that Array.

```js
class SomeDto {
// ...
       
// Array of Urls
@IsArray()
@IsUrl({each:true})
images: string[];

// ...
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to validate this Array of Urls.

Answer (score 7):

The type of the first parameter of `IsUrl` is not the usual `ValidationOptions` one.

You can check its signature:

```
export declare function IsUrl(options?: ValidatorJS.IsURLOptions, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions): PropertyDecorator;
```

So, try to pass the `{ each: true }` in the second place and it will work.

```
class SomeDto {
// ...
       
// Array of Urls
@IsArray()
@IsUrl({}, { each: true })
images: string[];

// ...
}
```